# How can I regroup a dataframe and accumulate a colume's values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
date                     price       volume
2017-10-17 01:00:11.031  51.91       1
2017-10-17 01:00:11.828  51.91       1
2017-10-17 01:00:12.640  51.91       1
2017-10-17 01:00:13.140  51.90      -9
2017-10-17 01:00:15.328  51.90      -5
2017-10-17 01:00:16.531  51.90       1
2017-10-17 01:00:16.531  51.89      -2
2017-10-17 01:00:19.937  51.90       1
2017-10-17 01:00:24.546  51.90       1
2017-10-17 01:00:25.250  51.90       1
2017-10-17 01:00:32.843  51.89      -9
2017-10-17 01:00:42.859  51.89      -5
2017-10-17 01:00:43.453  51.89      -1
2017-10-17 01:00:43.546  51.90       1
2017-10-17 01:00:45.953  51.90       7
...
```

I want to make a dataframe that shows how many volumes have been accumulated in every 5 minute, at each price level.

For example, if the highest and lowest prices between 2017-10-17 00:00 ~ 2017-10-17 00:05 were 51.21 and 51.11, the result would be:

```
datetime                 price       pos_volume     neg_volume
2017-10-17 00:00         51.21       3              4
                         51.20       21             23
                         51.19       44             21
                         51.18       31             33
                         ...
                         51.14       14             21
                         51.13       30             29
                         51.12       2              3
                         51.11       5              1
```

There are two columns to differentiate positive and negative volumes.

I think I could do this if I use many conditional loops, but I'd like know if there are more pythonic simple ways to do this. Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Have you seen `df.resample`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Oh, thank you! I'll look up it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate positive and negative values using `np.where`, then use pivot table with index as `grouper` with freq as 5 mins and then use `aggfunc` as `count` (it ignores nan values).

```
df['pos_vol'] = np.where(df['volume']>0,df['volume'],np.nan)
df['neg_vol'] = np.where(df['volume']<0,df['volume'],np.nan)

ndf = df.pivot_table(values=['pos_vol','neg_vol'],index=[pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5min'),'price'],aggfunc='count')
```

Output :

```
                           neg_vol  pos_vol
date                price                  
2017-10-17 01:00:00 51.89        4        0
                    51.90        2        6
                    51.91        0        3
```

For sorted index you can use `ndf = ndf.sort_index(level=1,ascending=False)`

Output :

```
                          neg_vol  pos_vol
date                price                  
2017-10-17 01:00:00 51.91        0        3
                    51.90        2        6
                    51.89        4        0
```

Comment: Nice, using `pd.Grouper`.

Comment: @ cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thankyou, answered a similar type of qn a week ago. So had that in mind.

Comment: @Bharath shetty Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @maynull glad can help